# adblock等におけるhrefのフィルター

Tags: html

hogeとfugaが両方、順不同でURL文字列(href属性の値)に含まれる要素を消したい場合、どのようなフィルタになるのでしょう？

```
a href="example.com/hoge/fuga"
a href="example.fuga.com/hoge"
```

などは消して、

```
a href="example.com/hoge"
a href="example.fuga.com"
```

など片方のみのURLでは消さないようにしたいです。
`:has-text`の使い方が悪かったのか、うまくいきませんでした。

adblockとuBlockで記法が変わらないとは思いますが、よろしくお願いします。
また追加すべきタグがあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

もしお使いの AdBlocker で**正規表現**が使えるのでしたら、

```
a href="[^"]*?hoge[^"]*?fuga[^"]*"
a href="[^"]*?fuga[^"]*?hoge[^"]*"
```

といった形で指定できるかもしれません。